# VBScript set focus on "No" button on UI window

Tags: vbscript, automation, terminal-emulator, secure-crt

I'm writing a VBScript script for use with VanDyke's CRT.  Is there a way to set the focus on the "No" button on a MsgBox automatically, instead of the default "Yes"?

```
val = MsgBox("Do you want to remove specials?",VBYesNo, "Purchasing Automation")
'6 == yes, 7 == no
If (val = 6) Then
    'we received a yes
    MsgBox("got a yes")
Else
    'no is inferred
    MsgBox("got a no")
End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `vbYesNo` with `vbYesNo OR vbDefaultButton2`.